# WebForm_DoCallback is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am getting an error where WebForm_DoCallback is undefined.

### EDIT

```
 WebForm_DoCallback("AccountPageControl1", "FileSave~" + fileName, CVFileSavedServerResponse, null, null, true);


function CVFileSavedServerResponse(param, context) {
}
```

Why isnt the WebForm_DoCallback working?

Also have to note that the form "action" attribute is changed, the change is only appending query strings before the Ajax Call is used could this be the problem?.

```
$(".inputfile").fileUpload({ fileExtAllowed: 'exe', fileSizeLimit: 200000, savePath: 'docs',

        fileFormatCheck: function(format) {

        },

        fileSizeError: function(size) {


        },

        fileProgress: function(length, progress) {
            $(".progressbarcvupload").show();
            $(".accounttext5").hide();
            var percentage = (progress / length) * 340;
            $(".progressbarcvuploadinner").css("width", percentage);
        },

        finish: function(fileName) {
            $(".progressbarcvupload").hide();
            $(".progressbarcvuploadinner").css("width", 340);
            $(".accounttext5").show();
            $(".accounttext5").text(fileName);

            GetFileNameCallback(fileName);

        }


    });
```

### EDIT

Ok i have registered the Callback server side

```
script += "function GetFileNameCallback(filename){" & Environment.NewLine
    script += "     " & Me.GetCallbackEventReference(Me, "'FileSave~' + filename", "null") & Environment.NewLine
    script += "}" & Environment.NewLine

    Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "GetFileNameCallback", script, True)
```

But the callback isnt being fired server side.

Comment: Please post the function definition of Webform_DoCallback

Comment: Post the actual function definition of WebForm_DoCallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the WebForm_DoCallback was undefined because the form action attribute was being modified before the callback was called. When i set the form action attribute back to its original state, the callback was working.

Comment: I do get this error in IE-11 and how could i solve this issue?
I don't get your point. please explain in detail.
I also pur App_browsers folder in website root, but it does not work.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

If this issue persists only in IE10 - it can be IIS issue. I've just faced with this problem: my customer said that his website stop woring in IE (as I found later - only in ie10). And it was realy broken - none of the controls worked.
Check the article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
you only need to update the file %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\%framework_version%\CONFIG\Browsers\ie.browser

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the [GetCallbackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getcallbackeventreference.aspx) method server-side in order for the required JavaScript file to be included.

Comment: But i have used WebForm_DoCallback in my code many times at those seem to work

Comment: Probably there are other controls which do postback that have caused the JS file registration.

Comment: But ICallbackEventHandler is registered with the server side control "AccountPageControl1"

Comment: As I said you need to call GetCallbackEventReference. Check MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx

Comment: I have registered the callback server-side now, but still doesnt fire server-side. I have edited the code above